Microsoft Graph client in a ASP.NET Core MVC web app error
I am trying to get some graph to get return some user attributes from Entra. I need to use graphClient.Me.GetAsync().
Update: My end result is that I need to use var result = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].GetAsync((requestConfiguration) => { requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string []{ "displayName","givenName","postalCode","identities" }; }); to get some attributes that graphClient.Me.GetAsync() does not return, and I believe that is only supported with Microsoft.Graph 5.61, but I could be wrong.
When I run my project from Visual Studio I get prompted for my Entra credentials, then I get this error message:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Graph.IAuthenticationProviderOption' from assembly 'Microsoft.Graph.Core, Version=3.1.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx'.

Here is my setup - I have added these packages:
Microsoft.Graph v.5.61
Microsoft.Identity.Web 3.2.2 
Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph v. 3.2.2

Added to appsettings.json:
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "your-tenant-id",
    "ClientId": "your-client-id",
    "ClientSecret": "your-client-secret",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
}

Added to Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add authentication and Microsoft Identity
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

// Add Graph API client
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftGraph(options =>
{
    options.Scopes = "User.Read"; // Ensure this scope is granted in Azure portal
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

And this is my controller:
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphClient;

    public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
    {
        _graphClient = graphClient;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        // Get the user's information
        var user = await _graphClient.Me.GetAsync();

        // Access the user's email
        var email = user.Mail ?? user.UserPrincipalName;

        ViewBag.Email = email;

        return View();
    }
}

Here is the csproj file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.61.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="3.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="3.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="3.2.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
I have tried different versions of the packages, different code in the Program.cs.

Please share your .csproj file.

@Baze2024 Try replacing dependency Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph with Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient.

@Baze2024 Uninstall the Microsoft.Graph v.5.61 package and try again.

@Harshitha I added the csproj

To fix the error, I uninstalled the Microsoft.Graph package and updated the code in Program.cs and HomeController.cs to retrieve user attributes from Entra using Microsoft Graph.
.csproj :
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.10" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="8.0.10" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.19.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="2.19.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.19.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.DownstreamApi" Version="2.15.2" />
</ItemGroup>

Program.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();

HomeController.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

namespace WebApplication15.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphClient;
        public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
        {
            _graphClient = graphClient;
        }

        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "MicrosoftGraph:Scopes")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var user = await _graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            ViewData["GraphApiResult"] = user.UserPrincipalName;
            return View();
        }
        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "MicrosoftGraph:Scopes")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserDetails(string userId)
        {
           var result = await _graphClient.Users[userId]
              .Request()
              .Select("displayName,givenName,postalCode,identities")
              .GetAsync();
           ViewData["DisplayName"] = result.DisplayName;
           ViewData["GivenName"] = result.GivenName;
           ViewData["PostalCode"] = result.PostalCode;
           ViewData["Identities"] = result.Identities;
          return View();
    }
    }
}

appsettings.json :
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<domain>",
    "TenantId": "<tenantID>",
    "ClientId": "<clientID>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read User.ReadBasic.All"
  }
}

index.cshtml :
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

<hr />

<div>
    <h2>Graph API Result - Current User</h2>
    <div><strong>User Principal Name:</strong> @ViewData["GraphApiResult"]</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div>
    <h2>Graph API Result - User Details</h2>
    <form method="get" action="/Home/GetUserDetails">
        <label for="userId">Enter User ID:</label>
        <input type="text" id="userId" name="userId" required />
        <button type="submit">Get User Details</button>
    </form>

    <div>
        <h3>User Details:</h3>
        <p><strong>Display Name:</strong> @ViewData["DisplayName"]</p>
        <p><strong>Given Name:</strong> @ViewData["GivenName"]</p>
        <p><strong>Postal Code:</strong> @ViewData["PostalCode"]</p>

        <h4>Identities:</h4>
        <ul>
            @if (ViewData["Identities"] is List<Microsoft.Graph.ObjectIdentity> identities && identities.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var identity in identities)
                {
                    <li>
                        <strong>Sign-in Type:</strong> @identity.SignInType <br />
                        <strong>Issuer:</strong> @identity.Issuer <br />
                        <strong>Issuer Assigned ID:</strong> @identity.IssuerAssignedId
                    </li>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <li>No identities found.</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

_UserDetails.cshtml :
<p><strong>Display Name:</strong> @ViewData["DisplayName"]</p>
<p><strong>Given Name:</strong> @ViewData["GivenName"]</p>
<p><strong>Postal Code:</strong> @ViewData["PostalCode"]</p>

<h4>Identities:</h4>
<ul>
    @if (ViewData["Identities"] != null)
    {
        var identities = (System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>)ViewData["Identities"];
        foreach (var identity in identities)
        {
            <li>@identity</li>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <li>No identities found.</li>
    }
</ul>

GetUserDetails.cshtml :
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "User Details";
}

<h2>User Details</h2>

<p><strong>Display Name:</strong> @ViewData["DisplayName"]</p>
<p><strong>Given Name:</strong> @ViewData["GivenName"]</p>
<p><strong>Postal Code:</strong> @ViewData["PostalCode"]</p>

<h4>Identities:</h4>
<ul>
    @if (ViewData["Identities"] is List<Microsoft.Graph.ObjectIdentity> identities && identities.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var identity in identities)
        {
            <li>
                <strong>Sign-in Type:</strong> @identity.SignInType <br />
                <strong>Issuer:</strong> @identity.Issuer <br />
                <strong>Issuer Assigned ID:</strong> @identity.IssuerAssignedId
            </li>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <li>No identities found.</li>
    }
</ul>

Output :
After successfully logging in, I got the below page. Then, I entered the user object ID and clicked on Get User Details as shown below.

User attributes :


Thanks! That works. 2 things, could you share you view code with me? Secondly, I am needing to get some attributes that come back null. I am trying to use this code
var result = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].GetAsync((requestConfiguration) => {  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string []{ "displayName","givenName","postalCode","identities" }; });
From the Microsoft article section Example 3: Use $select to retrieve specific properties of a user:
link Example 3.

@Baze2024 I updated the view code, will try and let you know to get the user attributes.

@Baze2024 I updated the answer to get user attributes.

Perfect. Thank you!!
